# do all dtos need to be serialized in rest call

Tags: json, web-services, rest, dto

I have a restful web service and at service side I have a dto and it will return to the front end in json format. Does that dto need to be serialized? I saw some posts mentioned that need to be serialized if it is across jvms. But in my case, I only need to get data from db and send back to client side in json/xml format. I don't see any chance need to make the object status.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To strictly answer your question, No. you do not need to serialize the DTO, since serialization is relevant where an object is serialized/de-serialized to/from byte stream, in your case json serialization first happens to a string and then byte stream. So as long as the String class (or whatever native classes) that your Json parser library uses, is serialized, you are safe.

However it is always best practice to serialize a deeply normalized dto/entity/pojo since you never know where it might be used tomorrow